# Does $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ mod the obvious $\mathbb Z$ action have more structure than just a set?

Tags: gr.group-theory, lattices, group-actions

$\mathbb Z$ acts on the lattice $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ by adding an element to itself n times.

I am studying some function arising from symplectic geometry which happens in my case to be naturally defined on $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ and is constant on each orbit of the $\mathbb Z$-action, thus it lives ob the orbit space.

I am curious what kinds of algebraic/geometric/arithmetic structures does this set or orbits has, to compare with the behaviour of my function.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify the action? If I understand correctly, it sounds like you have $n.(x,y)=(nx,ny)$, in which case (a) this is not a group action in the usual sense, and (b) orbits are problematic because $0.(x,y)=(0,0)$ for every $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The action I was expecting was rather $n \cdot (x, y) = (n + x, n + y)$, and I had even begun to comment as much! But that's not what the first sentence says. Are you sure that first sentence describes what you want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The set $(\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z)\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ modulo the equivalence relation $(x,y)\sim(nx,ny)$, for $n\in \mathbb Z_{\not =0}$, is known as $\mathbb Q\mathbb P^1$, the projective line over $\mathbb Q$. It's an algebraic variety over the rationals (or rather, it's more correct to say that it's the $\mathbb Q$-points of an algebraic variety over the rationals).

The set $(\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z)\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ modulo $(x,y)\sim(nx,ny)$, for $n\in \mathbb Z_{> 0}$, is not the $\mathbb Q$-points of an algebraic variety in any obvious way.